# Can't call method “send” on an undefined value at - Net::SSH::Expect Perl error

Tags: perl, ssh

I am running some commands in a remote server by connecting from my local server. To achieve this I am connecting to remote server using `Net::SSH::Expect` perl module. Connection is establishing here, but sometimes when I execute the command the following error comes up -

```
Can't call method "send" on an undefined value at .....
```

Here is my code:

```
my ($ip, $user, $passwd) = ("my.ip.address.here","user", "password");
my $ssh = SSH_Connection( $ip, $user, $passwd );

my $command_to_execute = "<Command to be executed will build here>";
print "$command_to_execute\n";
$str = 'Bye';
$ssh->send("$command_to_execute; echo $str");
$output = $ssh->waitfor($str, undef);
$ssh->close();
print "END\n";

sub SSH_Connection {
    my ( $host, $user, $passwd ) = @_;

    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
        host => $host, #ip
        user => $user, #'user'
        password => $passwd, #'password'
        raw_pty => 1,
        no_terminal => 0,
    );

    my $login_output;
    my $handledie = eval {
        $login_output = $ssh->login();
    };

    if ( $@ ) {
        if ($@ =~ m/SSHConnectionError/i ) {
            print  "SSH Connection Error\n";
        } elsif ( $@ =~ m/SSHProcessError/ix ) {
            print "SSH Process Error\n";
        } elsif ( $@ =~ m/SSHConnectionAborted/ix ) {
            print "SSH Connection Aborted\n";
        } else {
            print "SSH Unknown Error: $@\n";
        }
    }
    if ($login_output !~ /Last login/) {
        die "Login has failed.";
    } else {
        return $ssh;
    }
    print "SSH to ip - $host failed\n";
}
```

First I'm building the command and storing it in `$command_to_execute` variable.

At the end of command execution I'll get keyword `Bye`. So I am waiting for that keyword to match.

My question is -

1. Why I am getting above mentioned error?
2. Suppose if my command execution is failed, will the control will come back to my script ? Because its waiting for `$str` word.

I doubt about the error catching method is not proper. Please suggest a better solution.

Comment: As already mentioned in the [earlier duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710497/executing-command-in-remote-server-gives-cant-call-method-send-on-an-undefine?noredirect=1#comment103716829_58710497) you end up with an undefined value in `$ssh`. Probably the previous line of output contains an error message from your subroutine.

Comment: What could be the reason for that. Because if I run this script for 5 times, 2 times it is getting failed.

Comment: @vinodk89 I think maybe `my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (...)` returns `undef`.. but you are not checking for that, so the `sub` returns `$ssh` (which is `undef`)

Comment: @HåkonHægland, I agree. So how can I improve my script in this case.

Comment: @vinodk89 Hmm, from the [source](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-SSH-Expect/source/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pm#L25) it seems `new()` will not return `undef`, however it croaks on illegal arguments..